# SSIS Google Analytics Issue: "Unable to cast COM object"

Tags: sql-server, ssis, google-analytics-api, etl, sql-server-2012-datatools

I'm using the GA Analytics data source for Data Tools 2012.  I'm able to log-in and use the component within an SSIS package, debug and run the package, fetch and load data (to OLE DB target).  No problems!

But when I try to deploy the package to SSIS Catalog on local or remote servers, the package throws the following validation error: "Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSComponentMetaData100'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call to the COM component for the interface with IID '{887BD061-82D4-4F06-A222-33D4E7F896}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported"...

I've made sure to isolate the problem down to it's core.  I've created a package with only the GA data source on it, and ran into the same issue.  I have no problem deploying or executing any other ssis packages / components.

Aside from deploying the SSIS Package to the SQL Server SSIS Catalog, I've also tried to run the Execute Package Utility 2014 to run the package.  I run into the same validation / execution error as listed above.

The only way I can run this package now is to run it in debug mode through VS / DT 2012 - Manually!

Also, I feel like maybe the components OAuth session is being lost upon deployment.. and if it isn't.. I don't know how I would otherwise reset an OAuth connection for GA data source on a remote server (without having a VS/DT installed)..

Can anyone please help shed light on this issue?

- What is the proper deployment strategy for packages containing the GA SSIS DataSource?
- What would be an alternative and effective way to schedule such a package on a production server?
- Is there a known fix for this issue?

Comment: I think you should contact the company that created that tool.  I don't think you will get help for it on stack.

Comment: When you run it in VS, is this a different server to the SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. As it turned out I was using VS2012. The GA loader on VS2012 is compatible with MSSQL2012. To use the loader on MSSQL2014 you will need VS2013.

Hope this helps!